# SQL percentage calculation by category

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the percentage of all responses that are 'good' or 'very good' over the total received by date and team -. Is there a way to put a calculation within the case statement - all my attempts are not getting me anywhere? Or do I need to take a completely different approach?

SQL management studio working code so far:

```
SELECT 
  [Team]
 ,[response]
  ,[count]
  ,[date]
  CASE 
  WHEN  [Response] = 'Good' OR [response ] = 'Very good' THEN [count]  Else 0 end AS [positive]
  ,CASE
 WHEN [response] = 'poor' OR [response]  = 'very poor' then [count]  ElSE 0 
 END AS [negative]
 FROM [surveyresponse] Group by[Team], [response],[count],[date]
```

Data table with two additional fields
:

| Team | Response | Count | Date | positive | negative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Good | 100 | 20204 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | Very Good | 5 | 20204 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | Poor | 105 | 20204 | 0 | 105 |
| 1 | Very Poor | 205 | 20204 | 0 | 205 |
| 1 | Dont Know | 74 | 20204 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Dont Know | 34 | 20204 | 0 | 0 |

Desired

| Team | Date | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20204 | 33% (100/305) |
| 2 | 20204 | 5% (5/110) |

Comment: See https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/3419/conditional-aggregation or Google for "***sql conditional aggregation***".

Comment: Can you update your post with your DBMS, sample input table, current output and expected output?

Comment: Change `[count]` to 1. Then use `count()` around the whole expression. Make sure to avoid interger division.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with two conditional sums, whereas:

- the former will sum up all good responses
- the latter will sum up all responses which are either good or poor

```
SELECT Team,
       Date_,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Response LIKE '%Good' THEN Count_ END)
         / SUM(CASE WHEN Response <> 'Dont Know' THEN Count_ END) *100 AS perc 
FROM tab
GROUP BY Team,
         Date_
```

This will work with all the most common DBMS', unless you have some kind of legacy version that misses some of the employed operators here.

Note: Tend to avoid field names like "*Date*" and "*Count*", as they can be DMBS reserved words, and using them may lead to potential query errors.

Comment: here Response is not used in Group By Clause, so can't be used in query.

Comment: Good point, actually it depends a lot on the DBMS the author of the post is using. This solution was tested in a MySQL environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH temp AS (
SELECT 
  [Team]
 ,[response]
 ,[count]
 ,[date_]
 ,SUM([count]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Team]) AS Total
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN  [Response] LIKE '%good' THEN [count]  Else 0 END) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Team]) AS [Result]
 FROM [surveyresponse]
)
SELECT 
  [Team]
 ,[date_]
 ,[Result] / Total * 100 AS Percentage
FROM temp
```

This should work.